# Upstart Ubuntu Nodejs upload tmpdir error

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, file-upload, upstart

I'm running an Upstart daemon on Ubuntu.
The daemon is running a nodejs app when accepts files for upload.

When trying to upload a file I get following error:

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'tmpDir'
    at new Form (/var/vikiWhauAPI/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/node_modules/multiparty/index.js:53:44)
    at /var/vikiWhauAPI/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/multipart.js:100:18
    at limit (/var/vikiWhauAPI/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/limit.js:66:5)
    at multipart (/var/vikiWhauAPI/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/multipart.js:97:5)
    at /var/vikiWhauAPI/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/bodyParser.js:57:9
    at urlencoded (/var/vikiWhauAPI/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/urlencoded.js:52:72)
    at /var/vikiWhauAPI/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/bodyParser.js:55:7
    at json (/var/vikiWhauAPI/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/json.js:46:55)
    at Object.bodyParser [as handle] (/var/vikiWhauAPI/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/bodyParser.js:53:5)
    at next (/var/vikiWhauAPI/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:190:15)
```

Comment: You should add whatever detail you have: how are you trying to upload, any code, ... that will encourage other users to help you.

Comment: I'm trying to upload an image through and nodejs app using express

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS

Node v0.10.21